# Jsp scriplet works while jstl doesn't

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I have scriplet and jstl code that checks if a user's email is `root` and if so, add a div to a header. The scriplet code works, while jstl code doesn't.

scriplet code:

```
    <%
            if (user.getEmail().equals("root"))  {
                %>
        <div class="button logout-button"
             onclick="location.href =
                     '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/initializedatabase'">
            Initialize the database
        </div>
        <%
            }


        %>
```

jstl code:

```
 <c:if test =
          "${sessionScope.user != null} &&
           ${sessionScope.user.getEmail() == 'root'}">
           <div class="button initialize-button"
                onclick="location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/initializeddatabase'">
               Initialize Database
           </div>
        </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<c:if test =
      "${sessionScope.user != null} &&
       ${sessionScope.user.getEmail() == 'root'}">
```

to

```
<c:if test =
      "${sessionScope.user ne null && sessionScope.user.getEmail() eq 'root'}">
```

Comment: No, that didn't work ; (

Comment: Does it make error or nothing? If error show me the error. 
If nothing show me your controller source;;